# Error: 1064 MySQL Randomly started

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to connect to my MySQL database but I got the error 1604 `(Error: 1064 : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1)`. I don't know how this happened, cause it never happened before. It just randomly started.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
// Only process the form if $_POST isn't empty
if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {

  // Connect to MySQL
 $mysqli = new mysqli( '***', '***', '***', '***' );
// Check our connection
if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
die( 'Kan niet verbinden met database. Probeer het later opnieuw. ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
}

// Insert our data

$sql = "INSERT INTO inschrijven (naam, email, aantal,ip) VALUES ('{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['naam'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['aantal'])}','{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])}'";
     // validate agree unless you want to add 'checked' to one of the values

     $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);


 // Print response from MySQL
if ( $insert ) {
echo "U bent succesvol ingeschreven! U heeft bootnummer: {$mysqli->insert_id}. Op de naam: . U krijgt hiervan nog een bevesteging op uw mail, uw bootnummer kan nog veranderen. Hopelijk zien we u op de BotenBouwDag 2016!";
} else {
die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
}


$mysqli->close();
}

?>


<HTML>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<title>
Welkom op de officiële site van de BotenBouwDag 2016
</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="">
<input name="naam" id="naam" type="text">
<input name="email" id="email" type="email" autocomplete="off">
<input name="aantal" id="aantal" type="number">
<input type="radio" name="eten"> Ja 
<input type="radio" name="eten"> Nee
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Verstuur Informatie">
</form>

<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="address"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
$("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);



document.getElementById('city').value = response.city;
}, "jsonp");
</script>


</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: from a quick glance: you are missing a closing `)` in your query. Anyways, I'd prefer prepared statements.

Comment: @Sirko I can't see a a missing ")" and it also says in the error "line 1" which I think is the strangest part cause that only says "<?php"

Comment: "line 1" is referring to line 1 of you're SQL query, not line 1 of your PHP file.

Comment: Could this have something to do with a value which you are trying to insert? As you say this suddenly started happening, it implies that the query has worked up until a point.

Comment: just try to output the query before sending it. then you'll probably see it yourself.

Comment: Removed ambiguous tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has a missing `)` enclosing the `VALUES` on line 1:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO inschrijven (naam, email, aantal,ip) VALUES ('{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['naam'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['aantal'])}','{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])}'";
```

it should be

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO inschrijven (naam, email, aantal,ip) 
        VALUES (
          '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['naam'])}', 
          '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])}', 
          '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['aantal'])}',
          '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])}'
        )";
```